# Can I use a variable to set a path in FileStream?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, filestream

I have a test script in Selenium Webdriver using C# in which I read data from a `.txt` external file.

The path is fixed on the script, indicating a folder on my computer. But in the future other people will run this script in other computers and they will have to adjust the path manually directly on the script.

Is it possible to set the path `C:\Users\...\myData.txt` like a kind of a variable, I mean, not being permanent on the body of the script?

This is the part of the script:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Principal
    {
        IWebDriver driver = null;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
            options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }

        public class DataTXT
        {
            public string example1{ get; set; }
            public string example2{ get; set; }
            public string example3{ get; set; }
            public string example4{ get; set; }
        }

        public static IEnumerable DataTXT
        {
            get
            {
                string linha;
                using (FileStream readFile =
                new FileStream(@"C:\Users\...\myData.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(readFile, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));

                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        var column = line.Split(';');
                        yield return new DataTXT
                        {
                            example1 = column[0],
                            example2 = column[1],
                            example3 = column[2],
                            example4 = column[3]
                        };
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    readFile.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, why not making a button to choose the path ? or make it in the base directory like : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "myData.txt"; which will return the current directory of your app.

Comment: It is just a string yes you can use a string variable.

Comment: @Kaj, a button to set a path is out of question on an automated script.

Comment: @CarolCiola what about the base directory ?

Comment: @paparazzo, yes but how to set this variable to set a path not being permanent on the body of the script? If I set `pathVariable = @"C:\..."` it will be fixed on the script anyway.

Comment: @CarolCiola Yes you can use a variable.  How to assign the variable can be from user input.  Sorry I could not be of more assistance.

Comment: @Kaj, about the base directory, I don't know if it can work. Here is the situation: I have around 15 test projects on the Solution Explorer of Visual Studio. For each project I have to use different data on the tests. So that's why today I have a path described on the script for each project to read their own `.txt` file. If I set a variable to the path, I could read it from another `.txt` file, for instance, but I believe that it is too redundant.

Comment: @CarolCiola then you need some magic to do the trick for you since no other ways to do that. No buttons . No base directory with a file name. I think nothing will work though.

Comment: @Kaj yeah, but since I am new on automation testing and the battery of my crystal ball is low, I am really out of ideas to solve this. Thanks for the help anyway! Maybe someone already ran through this before and can give some Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved by making the relative path, same, adding my `.txt` from each project in Solution Explorer, in the respective `csprojs`.

Imagining that the solution is the root and placed my `.txt` in the same relative path used in the new `FileStream (path)`.

In Solution Explorer, right-clicked the `.txt` and went to `Properties`. `Under Copy To Output Directory > Copy if newer`.

@Kaj & @papparazzo, I'd be glad if you took off the negative votes of this question, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?   It is just a string.

```
public string FilePath { get; set: }
using (FileStream readFile =
new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
```

You can pass data in a command line

```
static int Main(string[] args)
```

Comment: @Kaj Yes, would it be better is I wrote textBox.text?

Comment: Then read it again. The question about making the path of the script not defined for a special PC, but a working path for all PC which will use the script.

Comment: But the program does not control where the user placed the file.

Comment: But your previous code will force the users to name their PC's and folders according to the OP PC name :)

Comment: Well, it doesn't answer the question yet. The OP wants a path working for all PC's in addition to that, the user can't use the directory according to OP because it's an automated script.

Comment: @Kaj Don't follow.  The program does not have control of where a user placed the file so that information will need to be read in from somewhere.

Comment: That's what I thought :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question a bit as I'm slightly new here. But if you are just wanting a path variable that isn't statically defined and can be changed by the users; you could use the [**config**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) file to define it and point to the config instead. (Or ConfigurationManager [**MSDN-ConfigManager**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx))

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do this.

1. You can create the path inside your project and know where it is relative to \bin.
2. I see you are using NUnit. NUnit has `TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory` that will return the path of the test dll. If you add the txt file to your solution and copy it in with the dll with a post-build event, it will always be in the `TestDirectory`.